# How to use variables in .innerJoin()?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

What I have is a code like this one below

```
var innerQuery = knex('foo_table').select('bar_column')
var joinTable = knex('some_table').select('bar_column')

knex(innerQuery).innerJoin(joinTable,joinTable.bar_column,innerQuery.bar_column)
```

it gives me

> routine: "errorMissingColumn"

I have tried giving tables allias but it was same mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knex does allow variables in `.innerJoin`, but the variable must be a function. It gets passed the query builder object (or, in the case of non-arrow functions, you can use `this.` as the query builder). So you could do something like this:

```
const innerQuery = knex('foo_table').select('bar_column')
const onBarColumn = qb => qb.on('foo_table.bar_column', '=', 'some_table.bar_column')
const joinTable = qb => qb('some_table').innerJoin('foo_table', onBarColumn)

innerQuery.innerJoin(joinTable)
```

You can build it up gradually like this if it works better for you. Obviously, the above helpers could be wrapped to make the arguments more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I will try it and give feedback soon!

Comment: Your was very helpful but I did not understood last part of ur answer therefore I did my code lil bit different like so:
`knex(innerQuery).innerJoin(joinTable,onBarColumn)`

Comment: The `knex` call is already in the variable `innerQuery`, so you don't need to repeat it :)